# Print the divisors of the number N and sum it in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have done print out the divisors and sum it. For example I enter the number 6, the divisor I get is 1,2,3,6 And the sum is 12.

```
N= input('N=');
divisors(N);
disp(sum(divisors(N)))
```

Actual ouput :

```
1   2   3   6
                12
```

My expect out put :

```
("result of 1+2+3+6="12)
```

I don't know how to print that format
Can anyone help me? thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly, you probably want to use `fprintf`.

```
N = 6;
d = divisors(N);
s = sum(divisors(N));

fprintf( 'Result of sum is %d\n', s ); 
% 'Result of sum is 12'
```

Generating the `1+2+3+6` string is a little work, a compromise might be just printing the array

```
fprintf( 'Result of sum([%s])=%d\n', num2str(d), s ); 
% 'Result of sum([1  2  3  6])=12'
```

You can use `strjoin` if you really want the `+` style

```
fprintf( 'Result of %s=%d\n', strjoin(strsplit(num2str(d),' '),'+'), s );
% 'Result of 1+2+3+6=12'
```

Comment: The last example is nice, lazy me would have just used a longer `formatspec` with `fprintf`. It makes me wonder though, could you have used `strrep` instead of the combination of `strsplit`/`strjoin`?

Comment: @Hoki probably could have used `strrep`, in my quick test it looked like `num2str` adds 2 spaces between elements in the string, but I wasn't sure if that was always the case once you have variable numbers of digits etc. However, `strsplit` will throw away any additional whitespace, so it's convenient here if you want to be lazy :)